# Facebook ban user

Tags: facebook, comments

I want to ban user from a comment box which is in a facebook application. However the comment box does not give me the selection delete post but only spam user and report. I add the tags:
meta property="fb:app_id" content="******"

meta property="fb:admins" content="{My facebook id}"

But still does not work. 
Do you have any ideas what goes wrong?

Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of to ban a user from a comment box is making him not see the comment box anymore. This can be done by getting his uid when connecting to your app and storing it in  a database and on launching the app you could set certain values for users.

Comment: I seek one more automatic solution. For example, if you go to your Facebook wall you can delete the other users comments and you will have the opportunity to ban them. But in my comment box i can not delete the post. I don t know if these is some parameters which i forgot.